# Регулярное выражение, которое захватывает первую попавшуюся цифру из строк

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Помогите составить регулярное выражение, которое захватывает первую попавшуюся цифру из строк.

Например:

1abc23de45

a1bc23de45

abc123de45

---

(1)abc23de45

a(1)bc23de45

abc(1)23de45

Правильный результат отмечен скобками.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Найти: `(^.*?)(\d)`
Заменить на: `$1\($2\)`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, а Вы можете переписать так, чтобы эта первая попавшаяся цифра менялась на символ 'a'?

Comment: Замените `\($2\)` на `a` в поле "Заменить на"

Comment: Супер, спасибо. ♡